# How can I detect units in a string?

Tags: javascript, string, algorithm, search

I have a problem with string search.
In my app, I need to display some topics inside units.
The topic titles are like these:

```
"Unit 1: First lesson"
"Unit 2 and 3: Introduction"
"Unit 4: Exercise"
"Unit 5 and 6: Social Networking"
```

As you can expect, I need to display the first topic in unit 1 and the second topic in both unit 2 and 3.
But I have no idea how can I detect which unit are the topics belonged to.
If you have any good idea, pls help me.

Comment: What is expected output?

Comment: If I input unit number, then I need to get the proper topic.
For example if I input 3, then I would get the second topic.

Comment: Is this inside of an array?

Comment: would you also have ranges...like "Unit 7-10: Text"

Comment: Not ranges. only combine units with 'and'. And of course the topics are stored in an array.

Comment: I would rather have a JSON string for myself if this was coming from server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can extract the numbers with a regex and match.

The following code creates an array of objects that contains the topic title an the units it belongs

```js
const topics = [
    "Unit 1: First lesson",
    "Unit 2 and 3: Introduction",
    "Unit 4: Exercise",
    "Unit 5 and 6: Social Networking"
];

const topicUnits = topics.reduce((acc, t) => {
    acc.push({ 
       topic: t,
       units: t.split(":")[0].match(/\d/g)
    })
   
    return acc;
}, [])

console.log(topicUnits)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve these using [`match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match):

```js
const units = [
  "Unit 1: First lesson",
  "Unit 2 and 3: Introduction",
  "Unit 4: Exercise",
  "Unit 5 and 6: Social Networking"
];

units.forEach(title => {
  // Only match on string before the ':'
  let unitNumbers = title.substr(0, title.indexOf(':')).match(/([0-9]+)/g);
  console.log(title, unitNumbers);
});
```

Hope this helps,